# VS2010 - Assembly Information

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies

Upgraded to VS2010 Ultimate and when right-clicking on a project -> properties -> application tab, you get the assembly information.  Right now it says Copyright Microsoft, etc.  I'd like to default this to our company's name so I don't have to do it by hand for each project.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think this setting depends on the data you entered when installing windows.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I've used is to use Linked AssemblyInfo.cs files. This is basically a AssemblyInfo.cs file that contains your company information and is put at the root of all the source code. Then all the projects just add this file as a link in their projects, Solution Explorer -> Add Existin Item -> .. select_file .. -> arrow_on_left_of_add_button -> Add As Link

See the answer from TcKs on this question [Using AssemblyInfo to automatically update multiple AssemblyInfo.cs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116140/using-assemblyinfo-to-automatically-update-multiple-assemblyinfo-cs-files)

Answer (score 0):

The "Company" value in a project's "Assembly Information" (which is also used in the "Copyright field") is pulled from the Windows Registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization
```

Note: on 64-bit machines if you're running Visual Studio as 32-bit, you'll need to configure this Registry value instead:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization
```